# Receiving "missing parameter type" when using underscore for input parameter on function literal

Tags: scala, parameters, function-literal

I have a `trait` with generic parameters which contains a method where I am attempting to define the default implementation as "empty".

```
trait MetaBase[T <: Throwable] {
  ...
  def riskWithEvent[V](
    vToEvaluate: => V,
    failureTEvent: FailureBase[T, V] => Unit = _ => ()
  ): TryBase[T, V] =
    ...
}
```

I am receiving a "missing parameter type" error at the underscore right after `failureTEvent: FailureBase[T, V] => Unit =`. I cannot figure out how to get the Scala compiler to let go of having to know the type information at that point as it isn't used or needed.

I considered changing the parameter to:

```
failureTEvent: Option[FailureBase[T, V] => Unit] = None
```

However, I don't like that the clients must now wrap their function in a `Some()`. I would much prefer to allow them to not specify the parameter, or specify the parameter without a wrapper.

Any guidance on this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe has to do with variance of FailureBase. You can `(_: Any) => ()` anyway.

Comment: default args may have other hazards: https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-7095

Comment: The `(_: Any) => ()` compiled (I still have lots of other code to get refactored before I can claim it worked). I'm confused why the underscore by itself doesn't essentially mean the same thing; i.e. whatever code the Scala compiler is generating should essentially be of the explicit form you identified. Is it worth opening a ticket with the Scala compiler team?

Comment: @som-snytt: If you would like to create an answer containing the solution contained in your first comment, I will happily accept it. If you prefer not to (or just don't), I will end up posting an answer myself so as to more explicitly show there is an answer and the context of the caveats. If/when I open a ticket with the Scala compiler team, I will post the ticket here.

Comment: What are the possible types for `_` that you wanted for your ideal solution i.e. if `_ : Any` is not good enough?

Comment: I didn't need any types at all. A sufficient solution was to provide an implementation that immediately returned `()`; i.e. an instance of `Unit`. My ideal solution was to provide the `_ => ()` where I assumed it was telling the Scala compiler to ignore all type information of the single input parameter (represented by the `_`) as it was obvious no type information was needed by the default function literal implementation (represented by the '()'). My assumption was provoding `_` for a single input parameter was compilation equivalent of `(_: Any)`. Apparently, it isn't.

Comment: This is the ticket. The type of the "default arg getter" might be the issue. https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-8884 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26767525/scala-case-class-type-does-not-take-parameters

Comment: One reason not to infer "the widest type that works": given `_.f`, it's difficult to search for all possible implicit conversions that provide the missing member. And hard to reason about which conversions apply.

Comment: ok, on those lines, this code: `val x = _.toString` should also compile because `toString` is available on all objects in Scala. So, the compiler should infer the LUB for `_` as `Any`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, it has trouble with the `V` param.

Here is `-Ylog:typer -Ytyper-debug`.

```
|    |    |    |    |    |-- ((x$1) => ()) : pt=FB[T,?] => Unit BYVALmode-EXPRmode (site: value g in MB) 
<console>:13: error: missing parameter type
       trait MB[T <: Throwable] { def f[V](g: FB[T, V] => Unit = _ => ()): Unit = () }
                                                                 ^
|    |    |    |    |    |    \-> <error> => Unit
```

Or,

```
scala> case class FB[T, V](t: T, v: V)
defined class FB
```

This works:

```
scala> trait MB[T <: Throwable, V] { def f(g: FB[T, V] => Unit = _ => ()): Unit = () }
defined trait MB
```

This doesn't:

```
scala> trait MB[T <: Throwable] { def f[V](g: FB[T, V] => Unit = _ => ()): Unit = () }
<console>:13: error: missing parameter type
       trait MB[T <: Throwable] { def f[V](g: FB[T, V] => Unit = _ => ()): Unit = () }
                                                                 ^
```

Or just take `Any`, since functions are contra-variant in the arg:

```
scala> trait MB[T <: Throwable] { def f[V](g: FB[T, V] => Unit = (_: Any) => ()): Unit = () }
defined trait MB
```

Other links related to default arg typing:

https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-8884

https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-7095

[Scala case class.type does not take parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26767525/scala-case-class-type-does-not-take-parameters)

Comment: Excellent answer! Tysvm for being so thorough. I know you put it in the comments on the original post already, but...would you mind putting a sidenote within your answer (at the bottom, if you like) about the ticket you opened to cover this? It means the person reading the answer would have all the context needed to know why they are on this tangent and that a possible fix in the Scala compiler in the future might happen based on the ticket. Tysvm.